# HTML href linked to another html file stuck on spinning circle

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link an image to another html file, but whenever I click on the image it gets stuck on a spinning loading circle forever. I'm pretty sure its because of the css, which makes it so when you hover over the image its turns darker and has "view" inside it. However, I can't seem to figure out how to make the href link to my other html file. Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
                <article class="col-6 col-12-xsmall work-item">
                    <a href="other.html" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs/img.png"
                            alt="other" /></a>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.image {
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.image:before {
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background: url("images/overlay.png");
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.25;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.image.thumb {
  text-align: center;
}

.image.thumb:after {
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 0.35em;
  border: solid 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  content: 'View';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 50%;
  line-height: 2.25em;
  margin: -1.25em 0 0 -3em;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.image.thumb:hover:after {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.image.thumb:hover:before {
  background: url("images/overlay.png"), url("images/overlay.png");
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Comment: There is some unclosed things and typos: https://jsfiddle.net/g9etw7qb/

Comment: The browser is not able to locate the `other.html` file. Make sure to provide the correct relative path to the file.

Comment: @Prashant I use the same path in another link that works fine, so I don't think the path is the issue

Comment: @sibert they are closed later, I just didn't include it in the post because there are more entries that follow

Comment: In order to test, you may use the full path: http://example.com/img/overlay.png. If this works, it could be a "path problem"...